# Mudar valor de span com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho os seguintes elementos :

```
<span class="teste">256,00</span>
<span class="teste">110,00</span>
<span class="teste">16,00</span>
<span class="teste">26,00</span>
```

Gostaria de saber um jeito de modificar cada valor  percorrendo o span e adicionando uma porcentagem a mais em cada valor. isso como código jQuery. alguém pode me ajudar nessa ? Esses são apenas exemplos.

Obrigado !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop do seu objeto  jQuery assim:

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(".teste").each(function() {
  var valorAtual = this.innerHTML;
  var valorFinal = calculaPorcentagem(valorAtual, 10); // Faz o calculo aqui. 
  this.innerHTML = valorFinal; // Atualiza o valor calculado.
});

function calculaPorcentagem(valor, porcentagem) {
  valor = parseFloat(valor.replace(",", "."));
  valor -= (valor / porcentagem);
  valor = valor.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");
  return valor;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="teste">256,00</span>
<span class="teste">110,00</span>
<span class="teste">16,00</span>
<span class="teste">26,00</span>
```

Comment: Não posso criar vários spans ids, a classe de span é uma só para todos os produtos. Exemplo, gostaria de dar um desconto de 10 reais em todos os spans com essa classe... queria uma função que fizesse isso, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Voce precisa para todos ou apenas para um valor escolhido randomicamente?

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu amigo... imagine o seguinte, eu tenho um site de vendas de produtos. cada produto tem seu preço, o preço dos produtos variam, mas são colocados na mesma span class. O que eu quero fazer é pegar o valor que esta na span class(ou seja o valor do produto), e dar uma porcentagem de desconto. ou seja se está com valor de 256,00 o valor vai mudar para 230,40. se eu der 10% de desconto.

Comment: Editei a resposta, acho que é isto, apenas percorrer os elementos com each e realizar o calculo de cada item, da uma melhoradinha na sua pergunta com estes detalhes que voce informou aqui, por que la eu compreendi algo de forma randomica, ate por que voce utilizou esta palavra, se tivesse dito  percorrer os elementos span e atualizar o valor de cada um teria sido bem mais eficaz esta resposta.

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado, funcionou, mas encontrei um problema, pois quando o valor é em milhar, ocorre um problema.

Comment: Amigo outra dúvida já me aproveitando de sua boa vontade rsrs, se no caso viesse R$ na frente de cada valor, como eu poderia fazer o calculo ?

Comment: Vamos lá, o foco da resposta é exatamente em como voce pode mudar o valor dos spans, conforme titulo, mas vou indicar um caminho a seguir, vocé precisa remover a mascara de dinheiro antes de fazer o calculo, tem varios plugins e codigos para isto, depois que voce fizer o calculo volte a mascara, quanto ao colocar R$ no valor tudo bem, contanto que voce se lembre de retira-lo para  calcular...

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar com esse código que remove a mascara para o calculo ?

Comment: http://blog.fmansano.com/javascript/converter-numero-para-moeda-e-vice-versa/ esse artigo te explica como...